# ajax toggle form js (rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using ajax to render a form to post on my `index` page directly.

```
= link_to "Post", new_post_path, class: "post-button", remote: true
```

That works as long as I'm using `.after()`

```
$('.post-button').after('<%= j render ("form") %>');
```

But, I'd like to use toggle--so that when the `post` button is clicked the form appears and when it's clicked again it disappears.

How do I combine the two features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
//index.html.haml
= link_to "Post", new_post_path, class: "post-button", remote: true
#post-form{ :style => "display:none;" }


//new.js.erb
$( '#post-form' ).html('<%= j render ("form") %>');
$( '#post-form' ).toggle( "slow", function() {} );
```